# JButton removing all the others jcomponent from a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I have this actionlistener added to a button:

```
//The ActionListener for the home button
ActionListener homeActionListener = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        removeAll();
        Home home = new Home();
        add(home);
    }
};
```

This is the code for jpanel and jbutton:

```
//creating the jpanel which will hold the buttons
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
buttonPanel.setBounds(0,0,600,100);
buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
add(buttonPanel);

//creating the jbutton to send the user to the home page
JButton home = new JButton("Home");
home.setBounds(25,25,100,50);
buttonPanel.add(home);
```

How can i make it so it deletes every component of the jframe except for that jpanel called buttonPanel?

Comment: Do you have other `JPanel`s on your form?

Comment: Not sure if this is able or not(don't have my computer at the moment), but try calling the removeAll() on the button panel and it should remove the items within the panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be to create a central panel which holds all the other components  and simply use `removeAll` on this container instead.

Be careful calling `removeAll` on a `JFrame`, it will remove the root pane which isn't really what you want.

And what HovercraftFullEels said

Answer (score 4):

1. Stop using null layout and `setBounds`. While using null layout may seem to a newbie the better way to create complex GUI's, it's a fallacy, and more you create Swing GUI's the more you learn to respect and use the layout managers and see that these creatures help immensely in creating flexible, beautiful and if need be, complex GUI's. Then you can let them size them selves appropriately by calling pack() prior to setting them visible.
2. Swap JPanels using a CardLayout. [Tutorial link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

.... and what MadP has to say!

Comment: thanks i don't intend on working with null layout , just for now cause i want to learn about swing more

Comment: @user3319763 Then you should focus on layout managers, Swing relies heavily on them

Answer (score 1):

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
```

removeAll() remove all component on frame.